# JAVA Replacing a char in a string with a int from a keyboard input

Tags: java

I am a freshman at university doing a software engineering degree.
So i have this assignment in java course where i have to encrypt a 6-digits password and display it to the user, one of the steps was to
**Replace the second digit with the remainder of the second digit divided by 2.**
I tried to do it using replace method but it  gives me an error saying that i can't replace a char with an int, here's my code :

```
public class Assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Password encrypter. ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a 6-digits passsword: ");
        final String password = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("encrypting your password:");
        char[] c = password.toCharArray(); 
        char temp = c[0];
        c[0] = c[5];
        c[5] = temp;
        String password1 = new String(c);
        char char2 = password1.charAt(1);
        int remainder = char2 % 2;
        String password2 = password1.replace(char2, remainder);
    }

}
```

(Here is the full exercise if someone is interested :
Question 1 - Password Encryption (4 pts)
Write a complete program that asks the user prompt a number with 6 digits and output the
encrypted password.
Your program should behave as follow:

1. Display a welcome message.
2. Ask the user for the input number.
3. Use a constant variable to store the input value in the program.
4. Display the encrypted number, which is equivalent by

1. Swap the 1st and 6th digits
2. Replace the second digit with the remainder of the second digit divided by 2.
3. Add 1 to the third digit of your input. Note that if the third digit is ‘9’, the third digit will
   be ‘0’ after Step 3), and there are no further changes to other digits from Step 3). Hint:
   use the remainder of the third digit after Step 3) divided by 10 to handle the possible
   overflow.
4. Replace the fourth digit with the remainder of the third digit divided by 3.
5. Swap the 4th and 5th digits.
   )

Comment: Do the replacement of the second char in the `c` array before constructing the new string. Don't try to replace it in the string, because that will replace all occurrences of the same digit.

Comment: Also, `String#replace(...)` replaces ALL matched substrings and not just that one character. Read it for yourself in the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Since you are learning, I recommend to ALWAYS go to the Javadoc for the class method you want to use and figure out what it does. Don't assume just by the name. My previous comment should have taught you that lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the `int` to a `char`. The two data types are not compatible, mainly because `ints` are 32-bit wide and `chars` are only 16-bits wide. To fix this, you must first convert the `int` to `char` and then do the opposite.

Also, do all of the manipulations of your `char` array before creating the new `String`

```
int digit = c[1];
char remainder = (char)(digit % 2);
c[1] = remainder;
// Add 1 to the third digit of your input
// Replace the fourth digit with the remainder of the third digit divided by 3.
// Swap the 4th and 5th digits.
String password = new String(c);
```

**UPDATE**:

After OPs comment to my post, I realized that my answer is not framed correctly based on the original problem statement.

The assumption now is that you start with a `String` that contains NUMERIC characters (i.e. "123456"). Then, each of these digits are manipulated according to the instructions. Therefore, when step 2 is executed, the result must be either a NUMERIC value of 0 or 1 must be added to that `char` array index.

If the above is correct, then the solution is simple:

```
System.out.println("Enter a 6-digits passsword: ");
final String password = keyboard.nextLine(); // assume "123456"
System.out.println("encrypting your password:");
char[] c = password.toCharArray(); // {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'} 

// swap first and last characters
char temp = c[0];
c[0] = c[5];
c[5] = temp; // c = {'6', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1'}

// Replace the second digit with the remainder of the second digit divided by 2
int digit = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2, 3)); // Takes second digit and converts it to a number
c[1] = String.valueOf(digit % 2).charAt(0); // calculate mod 2 and converts it to a char --> c = {'6', '0', '3', '4', '5', '1'}
```

A similar approach must be followed to manipulate the remaining characters in the array. Once all steps are completed, you can simply create a new `String` based on the `char` array. There are two ways of doing this:

```
String encodedPwd = String.valueOf(c); // recommended
String encodedPwd = new String(c); // Discouraged
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i did it and there's no error but i tried displaying it just to see if it works and i noticed a problem, if the remainder is 0 it leaves a white space and if it's 1 it displays a box with a question mark in it, do you know how i can solve this problem? thank you.

Comment: I do... maybe I misunderstood your initial problem. When you convert a numeric string (i.e. "123456") and convert it into a `char` array, you end up with '1', '2', '3', etc. If you then take these `chars` and convert them to integers, you are going to end up with the ASCII value of that character, not with the numeric value. I will modify my answer slightly.

Comment: @oussama If it help you consider upvoting it

Comment: @oussama pseudocoding before writing actual code helps a great deal when you are learning. Even for me, who have been doing this for almost 20 years, I often write down in plain English what the the process should do and then I take that narration and put it into code. Also, did you see what I did with putting the array values in the comments? It helps to write down the expected result of each step so that when you debug your code, you can compare your expected results with the actual result. Do this every time and you won't regret it. Trust me.